# Install MySQL with ansible on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant, ansible

I have a problem installing MySQL with ansible on a vagrant ubuntu,

This is my MySQL part

```
---
- name: Install MySQL
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - python-mysqldb
    - mysql-server

- name: copy .my.cnf file with root password credentials
  template: 
    src: templates/root/.my.cnf
    dest: ~/.my.cnf
    owner: root
    mode: 0600

- name: Start the MySQL service
  service: 
    name: mysql 
    state: started
    enabled: true

  # 'localhost' needs to be the last item for idempotency, see
  # http://ansible.cc/docs/modules.html#mysql-user
- name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
  mysql_user: 
    name: root 
    host: "{{ item }}" 
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}" 
    priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
  with_items:
    - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
    - 127.0.0.1
    - ::1
    - localhost
```

And I have this error

```
failed: [default] => (item=vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64) => {"failed": true, "item": "vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64"}
msg: unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or ~/.my.cnf has the credentials
failed: [default] => (item=127.0.0.1) => {"failed": true, "item": "127.0.0.1"}
msg: unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or ~/.my.cnf has the credentials
failed: [default] => (item=::1) => {"failed": true, "item": "::1"}
msg: unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or ~/.my.cnf has the credentials
failed: [default] => (item=localhost) => {"failed": true, "item": "localhost"}
msg: unable to connect to database, check login_user and login_password are correct or ~/.my.cnf has the credentials
```

my .my.cnf is

```
[client]
user=root
password={{ mysql_root_password }}
```

and when copied on the server

```
[client]
user=root
password=root
```

I don't understand why, ~/.my.cnf is created

Project [Github](https://github.com/ajouve/vagrant-php)

Thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When `mysql-server` is installed headlessly, there's no password. Therefore to make `.my.cnf` work, it should have a blank password line. Here's what I tested with for a `.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
user=root
password=
```

It's also slightly strange to put `.my.cnf` in your `vagrant` user directory as owned by root and only readable as root.

After ensuring the password was blank in `.my.cnf`, I was able to properly set the password for root in those four contexts. Note that it fails to run after that, since `.my.cnf` would need to be updated, so it fails the idempotency test.

There's a note on the ansible mysql_user module page that suggests writing the password and **then** writing the `.my.cnf` file. If you do that, you need a `where` clause to the `mysql_user` action (probably with a file stat before that).

Even more elegant is to use `check_implicit_admin` along with `login_user` and `login_password`. That's beautifully idempotent.

As a third way, perhaps `check_implicit_admin` makes it even easier.

Here's my successful playbook showing the above, tested with a few fresh servers. Kinda proud of this. Note `.my.cnf` is unnecessary for all of this.

```
---
- hosts: mysql
  vars:
    mysql_root_password: fart
  tasks:
  - name: Install MySQL
    apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600 state=present
    sudo: yes
    with_items:
    - python-mysqldb
    - mysql-server
  #- name: copy cnf
  #  copy: src=.my.cnf dest=~/.my.cnf owner=ubuntu mode=0644
  #  sudo: yes
  - name: Start the MySQL service
    sudo: yes
    service: 
      name: mysql 
      state: started
      enabled: true
  - name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
    sudo: yes
    mysql_user: 
      name: root 
      host: "{{ item }}" 
      password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
      login_user: root
      login_password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
      check_implicit_admin: yes
      priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
    with_items:
      - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
      - 127.0.0.1
      - ::1
      - localhost
```

(edit- removed my.cnf)

Comment: @ant are you trying on a new server or on one that had a partial install done? If the latter, ensure `.my.cnf` does not exist, then manually verify the root password.

Comment: I' doing a vagrant provision

Comment: right, did you `vagrant destroy` it? Did you delete the `.my.cnf`? Did you manually verify the root password?

Comment: try to remove strings with `login_user` and `login_password` lines from upper example. From this [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1266) it seems that if credentials are specified they are used even if `check_implicit_admin=yes`

Comment: for current versions of ansible, s/sudo/become_user/g in the above working playbook!

Comment: how do you use the unset password to set the password?

Comment: I'm getting an error "msg": "No package matching 'python-mysqldb' is available"

Answer (score 16):

Here is my complete working MySQL role, that might help you.

**vars/main.yml** :

```
mysql_root_pass: mypassword #MySQL Root Password
```

**asks/main.yml** :

```
---
 - name: Install the MySQL packages
   apt: name={{ item }} state=installed update_cache=yes
   with_items:
     - mysql-server-5.6
     - mysql-client-5.6
     - python-mysqldb
     - libmysqlclient-dev

 - name: Update MySQL root password for all root accounts
   mysql_user: name=root host={{ item }} password={{ mysql_root_pass }} state=present
   with_items:
     - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
     - 127.0.0.1
     - ::1
     - localhost

 - name: Copy the root credentials as .my.cnf file
   template: src=root.cnf.j2 dest=~/.my.cnf mode=0600

 - name: Ensure Anonymous user(s) are not in the database
   mysql_user: name='' host={{ item }} state=absent
   with_items:
     - localhost
     - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"

 - name: Remove the test database
   mysql_db: name=test state=absent
   notify:
     - Restart MySQL
```

**templates/root.cnf.j2**

```
[client]
user=root
password={{ mysql_root_pass }}
```

**handlers/main.yml**

```
---
 - name: Restart MySQL
   service: name=mysql state=restarted
```

**site.yml**

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  roles:
    - mysql
```

If you need any help, please check this github [link](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-roles/blob/master/LEMP/tasks/mysql.yml). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 20.04, it requires login_unix_socket now:

```
- name: setting default root password
  mysql_user:
    name: root
    password: "{{ mysql_root_password }}"
    check_implicit_admin: true
    login_unix_socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Cheers