# Automate MySQL install on Ubuntu 14.04 using Ansible

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, ansible

I'm trying to setup a Vagrant environment involving a few Ubuntu machines with Ansible and am having trouble writing an Ansible Playbook to automate the process. Primarily, I'm following the instructions from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598887

Here is the snippet of the error I'm getting from running the playbook;

```
PLAY [web] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [business-web1]

TASK: [Install MySQL] ********************************************************* 
failed: [business-web1] => (item=mysql-server) => {"failed": true, "item": "mysql-server"}
stderr: start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

stdout: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...

msg: '/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"   install 'mysql-server'' failed: start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/home/vagrant/provision-business-mysql.retry

business-web1              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

To the best of my understanding, it looks like the first 'install mysql' step isn't being run. To verify this, I managed to recreate the problem by running the ansible module directly from command line;

```
vagrant@mgmt:~$ ansible web -m apt -a "name=mysql-server update_cache=yes cache_valid_time=3600 state=latest" --sudo
business-web1 | FAILED >> {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef\" -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"   install 'mysql-server'' failed: start: Job failed to start\ninvoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action \"start\" failed.\ndpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):\n subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:\n mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:\n  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.\n\ndpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\nNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.\nErrors were encountered while processing:\n mysql-server-5.5\n mysql-server\nE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)\n",
    "stderr": "start: Job failed to start\ninvoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action \"start\" failed.\ndpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):\n subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1\ndpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:\n mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:\n  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.\n\ndpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):\n dependency problems - leaving unconfigured\nNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.\nErrors were encountered while processing:\n mysql-server-5.5\n mysql-server\nE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)\n",
    "stdout": "Reading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state information...\nmysql-server is already the newest version.\n0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.\n2 not fully installed or removed.\nAfter this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.\nSetting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...\n"
}

vagrant@mgmt:~$
```

Any idea how I can get mysql installed and a DB setup using Ansible?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `apt-get install mysql-server` directly on the server? That’s the place to start with testing this, and should make this easier to debug.

Comment: @MicahElliott I'm familiar on the manual steps - but I want to automate mysql server installation using ansible. It's a new tool for me and well .. its inner workings are not of interest to me.

Comment: Why not use an existing role from ansible galaxy? I prefer to use this [one](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/509).

Answer (score 5):

I had this same error occurring trying to install mysql on a fresh ubuntu/trusty64 box. Crazily enough it turned out to be due to the VM instance having less than 512MB of memory. Make sure your Vagrantfile allots your VM enough memory.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.memory = "512"
end
```

Comment: This IS an interesting possibility! At the time I was trying this out, my host system wasn't exactly a powerhouse and I was setting up guest OSs with about 256MB or less. Will need to check this out later. Thanks!

Comment: *allots a lot of space*  hey it worked!  thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for this! I ran into the same.

Comment: I had to use `vb.memory = 1024`… then it WORKED!! Thank you sooooo much for this post! I would have never solved this on my own. _PS: I'm setting up a Vagrant box (ubuntu/bionic64 (virtualbox, 20180920.0.0)) with MySQL 8._

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck in this problem for days using Vagrant 2.2.7 and Ansible 2.8.3, thinking it was related to `mysql-server-5.6` package.

Answer (score 0):

@MicahElliott points into the right direction. The error is not related to ansible, but to apt.

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
>
> stdout: Reading package lists...
>   Building dependency tree...
>   Reading state information...
>   mysql-server is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
>   2 not fully installed or removed.

Look here for a solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/438843/231051