# Ansible set root user password

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am newbie in ansible, I need to install mysql in server for that i wrote a playbook

```
---

- hosts: webservice
  tasks:
  - name: Install MYSQL Server
    apt:  name=mysql-server update_cache=yes state=latest

  - name: Install MYSQL Client
    apt:  name=mysql-client update_cache=yes state=latest
```

It installed successfully, but I want to write ansible playbook where I mention mysql root password, how can I do it.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597926/install-mysql-with-ansible-on-ubuntu should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the [mysql_user module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mysql_user_module.html)?

```
- mysql_user: name="root"
              password="your-NEW-password"
              check_implicit_admin=yes
              login_user="root"
              login_password=""
              state=present
```

With a blank password, not sure what the module expects. If it fails, try to remove the line with `login_password`.

It requires the `MySQLdb` Python package on the remote host. For Ubuntu, this command will work: `apt-get install python-mysqldb`, or as an Ansible task:

```
- apt: name=python-mysqldb
       state=present
```